# translating a problem to a differential equaton

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I've got a question like this:

```
The country's population has doubled in 50 years. 
In a few years it will increase threefold, 
assuming that the growth rate is proportional to the number of residents?
```

in the context of learning to solve first order differential equations.
How can I translate it to a differential equation form?

Comment: Let $x(t)$ denote the population in an instant $t$.

Assuming growth rate is proportional to the number of residents, means $x'(t)=k x(t)$.

The condityion of doubled in 50 years allows you to calcyulate the constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p(t+50)=2p(t)$

$$p'(t)=kp(t)\to p(t)\to C e^{k t}$$
$$p(t+50)=2p(t)\to e^{k(50+t)}=2e^{k t}\to k=\frac{\log (2)}{50}\approx 0.013863$$
How many years will pass before population will be three times, means solving
$$Ce^{kt}=3Ce^{kt_0}\to t=t_0+79.25\text{ years}$$